# Is it possible to have a light in a scene not affect a volume in Eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, volumetrics

I have a scene with a volume encapsulating the scene, to get some nice atmosphere and light scatter.  However, I now want to add a spotlight to hilight an object, but I dont want that spotlight affecting the volume/atmosphere.  Is there a way to do this in Eevee?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need to do it with the Compositor